# How to get a list of available VPN connections on the system via the command line?

Tags: cmd.exe

I'm trying get list of VPN connections configured in the system.

Searching the internet found this command line:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

But it only shows network adapters, no VPN connections are shown.

[image]

VPN connections were added using window's built-in "Set up a new connection or network" wizard.

Are there other methods I could use to get the list via CMD?

Comment: I don't use that - too insecure.  Try this:   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/get-vpnconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: What's insecure?

Comment: Microsoft VPN has been compromised mostly because it lacks IPSec security or very similar security

Comment: Which illustrates the reason you should edit your question to insure the information remains

Comment: Did you get the list you need from the Microsoft article?

Comment: No, it requires powershell. the systems I'm working with, has powershell v1.0 and it doesn't have VpnModule.

Comment: Try a more advanced version of Power Shell. The document I posted has clear steps for getting a VPN list and the article has examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, still no go, installed PS 7.2.6 and still getting the same error.